# GTK 2.0 Linker Error in Dev C++

Tags: windows, gtk, dev-c++, gtk2

So I found some tutorials on how to configure gtk to dev c++. I followed that tutorial very closely but when i tried to run this:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
static void hello( GtkWidget *widget,
               gpointer   data )
{
    g_print ("Hello World\n");
}

static gboolean delete_event( GtkWidget *widget,
                          GdkEvent  *event,
                          gpointer   data )
{
     g_print ("delete event occurred\n");
     return TRUE;
}
static void destroy( GtkWidget *widget,
                 gpointer   data )
{
    gtk_main_quit ();
}

int main( int   argc,
      char *argv[] )
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *button;
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect (window, "delete-event",
          G_CALLBACK (delete_event), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy",
          G_CALLBACK (destroy), NULL);
    gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 10);
    button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Hello World");
    g_signal_connect (button, "clicked",
          G_CALLBACK (hello), NULL);
    g_signal_connect_swapped (button, "clicked",
              G_CALLBACK (gtk_widget_destroy),
                          window);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), button);
    gtk_widget_show (button);
    gtk_widget_show (window);
    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}
```

It produces linker error like this:
`[Linker error] undefined reference to g_print`

And many more of this type.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Please show us what parameters you pass to the linker. This should be a call to `pkg-config`.

Comment: `-Ic:/GTK/include/gtk-2.0 -Ic:/GTK/lib/gtk-`

Comment: Read this: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2007-February/msg00127.html

Comment: You should copy/paste the result of `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0` and paste that in dev-c++ where you input the linker settings of your project. What you have pasted above is clearly incomplete, and is a part of what `--cflags` returns, not `--libs`.